# best statistical method for comparing groups of students

Tags: descriptive-statistics

If I want to compare one group of students learning online in year one, then compare a different group of students learning in person year 2 (same courses) on a quantitative standard which is best statistical method?

Comment: What do you want to compare?

Comment: number of students passing versus all students in each course to see if online or face to face is better

Answer (score 0):

If your sample size is big enough and follows a Gaussian distribution, you can use a t-test. Because you probably want to test all alternatives you want to use a two-tailed t-test (H0: mean(group1) - mean(group2) = diff = 0, H_alternative1: diff>0, H_alternative2: diff<0, H_alternative3: diff!=0 . Otherwise if you only want to test one direction you can use a one-tailed t-test, which I would not recommend here (H0: mean(group1) - mean(group2) = diff >= 0, H_alternative: diff<0 // or // H0: mean(group1) - mean(group2) = diff <= 0, H_alternative: diff>0).
If your data does not follow a normal distribution, you can apply non-parametric tests. These can be used for any type of distribution. A Wilcoxon-Test would be appropriate here.

Comment: What if you have Gaussian distributions but sample sizes of $2?$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose 95 out of 120 students passed the online class
and 80 out of 93 passed the face-to-face class.

**Test of two binomial proportions.** Then
respective proportions of students passing are $\hat p_1=0.79$ and
$\hat p_2 = 0.86.$ A two-sided whether the true
population proportions differ uses $H_0: p_1=p_2$
against $H_a: p_1 \ne p_2.$ There are various versions
of this 2-sample test for equality of proportions. The version implemented in R as `prop.test` gives P-value
$0.195 > 0.05$ so you do not reject $H_0$ at the 5% level.
[With about 1oo subjects in each class, it would not
be remarkable to find proportions as different as observed here.]

```
prop.test(c(95, 80), c(120, 93), cor=F)

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  c(95, 80) out of c(120, 93)
X-squared = 1.6796, df = 1, p-value = 0.195
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.16977402  0.03267725
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.7916667 0.8602151
```

*Note:* Slightly different tests of two binomial proportions are
implemented in various statistical software programs. (Differences center on continuity correction, whether
a normal or chi-squared distribution is used, and whether
the null hypothesis is used to find the standard error for the test.

**Chi-squared test of 2-by=2 table.** Alternatively, you could make a $2\times 2$ table of
these data, as follows:

```
TBL = rbind(c(95,80),c(20,7))
TBL
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   95   80
[2,]   25   13
```

In R, a chi-squared test of homogeneity gives the same
P-value as for the test of proportions:

```
chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 1.6796, df = 1, p-value = 0.195
```

*Note:* Chi-squared tests of 2-by-2 tables are similar in most
software programs. Many give an option to use Yates' continuity correction, which is not necessary for moderately
large samples. Most software programs show an error message
if the counts in the four cells of the table are too small
for a reliable P-value.

**Fisher exact test.** Especially if there are not enough data
for `prop.test` and `chisq.test` to give useful P-values
you could use Fisher's exact test, which gives about
the same P-value for my fictitious data as do the two
tests just above.

```
fisher.test(TBL)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TBL
p-value = 0.2116
alternative hypothesis: 
 true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2718405 1.3528189
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
 0.6188721
```